# Selecting range of text by start and end pattern in terminal

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed, terminal

Given an opening and closing pattern I would like to select all text in that range, including new lines that matches this pattern.

For ex.

```
➜  diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            250.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Macintosh HD           +249.8 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 A200C898-46E7-4C85-B946-35677A6880C6
                                 Unlocked Encrypted

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS m                       999.3 GB   disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk2s3
```

I'm interested in selecting the external drive and all of it's entries. The opening pattern (that I'm thinking of) would be `/(external, physical)/` and the closing pattern should probably be `/^$|^\n$/`.

The end result should be

```
diskutil list | "magic"
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS m                       999.3 GB   disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk2s3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` version: `awk '/start-string/,/end-string/' input`

```
diskutil list |awk '/external, physical/,/^$/'
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS m                       999.3 GB   disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk2s3
```

Comment: thank you, you've made some Apple users very happy today :) https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50399 (see my reply on that thread dated Mar 21, 2017 12:11 AM)

Answer (score 4):

Using address range:

```
diskutil list | sed '/(external, physical)/,/^$/!d;'
```

**How it works:**

- `/(external, physical)/,/^$/`: from line matching `(external, physical)`  up to next blank line
- `!d`: do not delete lines

Answer (score 1):

In case the range you'd like to output is not in the end of the file, use:

```
$ awk '/^\/dev\/disk/{f=0} /external, physical/{f=1} f' file
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS m                       999.3 GB   disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk2s3
```

Explained:

```
/^\/dev\/disk/ { f=0 }        # flag down at new disk entry
/external, physical/ { f=1 }  # flag up at desired start point
f                             # output when flag up
```